# Manipulating the area outside a centered circle in a bitmap, in C - suggestions?

Tags: c, algorithm, image-processing

I have a 8bit-bitmap 1440:1080 image, with a centered circle on it. Now, I want to manipulate everything that's **outside** that circle. The image is pointed by the pointer `*img`.

I was thinking of doing it with distances, like this pseudo-code below:

```
unsigned char* img;

for (l = 0; l < width; l++) {
    for (j = 0; j < height; j++) {
        if(sqrt(pow(x2-x1,2) + pow(y2-y1,2)) > radius ){
            *(img + j * width + l) = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Like you probably noticed, my problem is how to relate `x1,x2,y1,y2` to `j` and `l`.

I was thinking of making a function like this:

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} coord;

coord getCoords(int index, int width){
    coord output;
    output.y=0;
    while(index>=width){
        index=index-width;
        output.y+=1;
    }
    output.x=index;
    return output;
}
```

And the input `index` would be `j * width + l` for the pixel I'm trying to know if it's inside the circle or not. The center pixel is [720,540] or if I make it a float to be more precise [720.5, 540.5].

Am I wrong? Or is there a better way to do this?

**PS**: it's just simpler to create to local variables for coordinates inside the function, and do the math (the distance calculation) inside the function and return a `bool`. Instead of creating a new type of variable.

Comment: The center of the image is [720, 540], which is at the corner of 4 pixels. A pixel is a square (or a rectangle if you have an aspect ratio that's not 1) - for example the pixel at index [12, 15] goes from (real x, y) 12<=x<13 and 15<=y<16. Similarly, your whole image goes from (real x, y) 0<=x<1440 and 0<=y<1080.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: didn't even know that forum. Thanks, will keep in mind for any posts like this in the future. But kinda weird since here in stackoverflow there's specifically a part of the post in the post-creator that is directed to "what has been tried". I assumed it could be "what will be tried" as well.

Comment: @PaulHankin That depends on the display function, it is not a universal truth. Some draw pixels from -0.5, with the fist pixel centered around 0. And in some systems indexing starts at 1.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz This question is not suited for Code Review, it does not contain complete code.

Comment: the lack of [mre] would also disqualify it for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
pow(l-xc, 2) + pow(j-yc, 2) > pow(radius, 2)
```

Comment: what? you're right. Why did I think `j` and `l` weren't coordinates...

Comment: @ATSlooking4things Perhaps come up with better, more intuitive variable names instead of one-letter ones. `l` in particular is a very problematic variable name because it looks like `1` (one) on some fonts.

Comment: @Lundin: in this particular case, the choice is difficult because the variables are at the same time indexes to an array (hence i, j, k... or r, c - for row, column - are appropriate), and geometric coordinates (hence x, y are virtually a must). In math-oriented code, single letter identifiers are not unsuitable.

Comment: @YvesDaoust No, "r, c for row column" aren't appropriate. `row` and `col` are appropriate...

Comment: @YvesDaoust Because readable = good, cryptic/mysterious/obfuscated = bad?

Comment: @YvesDaoust It couldn't possibly also mean radius or radians or result or return code or read _in the context of the program you are currently writing_, so what can go wrong... Use common sense and pick unambiguous identifier names.

Comment: @YvesDaoust It's a well-known problem/phenomenon when "math people" are picking up programming and then ditch out some 20+ one letter identifiers.

Comment: @Lundin: say "algorithm people".